# Event change of table in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Private Sub Document_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set table = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
If Not Intersect(table, Target) Is Nothing Then
Target.AutoFormat ApplyColor: Red
End If
End Sub
```

I have the following code, but it does not seem to work in VBA Word.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you copied the code from Excel VBA and tried to rebuild it a bit.
There are a few differences between Excel and Word VBA.

1. `Intersect` does not exist in Word VBA.
2. `DocumentChange` event in Word works differently from what you would expect - It occurs when a new document is created, when an existing document is opened, or when another document is made the active document. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822189.aspx)

If you want to make changes in red, you may do the following:

1. Record the wholeDocument in a static string.
2. When there is a change - record again in a new string.
3. Compare the strings and color the differences.

However, this is a bit tough, as far as word does not have `Change`event as we are expecting it (e.g. as in Excel). Thus, you should run the VBA code a few times automatically.