# Avoid seeing "restrict editing" sidebar - MS WORD

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a template and then restricted the editing to specific areas.

I added a simple macro to avoid seeing the yellow highlighting

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = False
```

Now I want to avoid that when a user tries to modify a restricted area, the "Restricted Editing" sidebar appears.

I recorded a macro to see what instructions VBA reads, but there is no command to open the sidebar...

Do you think there is a way to avoid the sidebar appearing? If I was in excel, I would think about something like:

```
 Private Sub RestricEditing_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Determine whether the change is in the restricted editing area
   Set checkRange = Application.Intersect(Target, restricted area)

' If the change wasn't in this range then we're done
   If checkRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Else "do not show the restricted editing sidebar"
```

Thanks in advance to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

When I use the following, the taskpane appears to be "disabled" for the user. It can still be shown via the "Restrict Editing" button in the Developer tab of the Ribbon:

```
Application.Taskpanes(wdTaskPaneDocumentProtection).Visible = False
```

To "disable" this pane when the document is opened I've had to resort to some trickery - and the pane in question will be visible for a moment. This assumes that the very start of the document should not be editable. `SendKeys` will trigger the pane; the disable is called on a timer.

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = False
    SendKeys "T"
    DoEvents
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "DisableProtectionPane"
End Sub

Sub DisableProtectionPane()
    Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneDocumentProtection).Visible = False
End Sub
```

I note that

- when the user dismisses the taskpane by clicking the "x" at the top right, the behavior is the same as using the above code.
- both this setting and that of the highlighting are reset to default when the document is closed and opened again.
- that using `Application.Taskpanes(wdTaskPaneDocumentProtection).Visible = true` does not necessarily reset the behavior during a Word session.

Comment: I can't replicate that. I can put that statement in the Document_Open() and it prevents it from displaying automatically when it's opened. But it still shows up at least once the first time you type in a restricted area.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also cannot replicate this behaviour (both in Office 2013 on win 8.1 and Office 2016 on win 10).
The pane keeps on appearing the first time I try to edit the restricted area, that is what I want users not to see.
This is anyway an improvement, although as we can see from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469988/event-change-of-table-in-word), there is no `change` event, so I think it is not possible to do what I want.

Comment: Ah, disable when the document is opened... I found something that seems to work - I've added it to my Answer, but no guarantees.